# Build project with one command with spring boot maven plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot.

I've got a maven project with several modules and there are some modules with web services, which I want migrate to Spring Boot Web (so they could run from jar file without deploying to server).

And I want build that with one command - smth like

```
mvn clean install package spring-boot:repackage
```

For that I included to parent pom spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-starter-parent and spring-boot-starter-web I included to every service module's pom.

Now I've got a problem: I cant build all with one command, because spring-boot-maven-plugin applies to every module, but I want it to apply to service modules.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if you want to work with multimodule projects I recommended you the following architecture *(read the README.adoc file to understand the module division)*:

https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-multimodule

After read that, now you understand that the `application` module (that one that contains the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class) is the unique one that should contain the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and all the `spring-boot-starter-*`.

So, you need to compile/install all your entire project from the parent using the following command:

`mvn clean install`

After that, you need to access to the `application` module and execute the `mvn spring-boot:run` command to execute your application.

Hope it helps,